# Pull a single item from json and display in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array in a JSON file and what I want to do is pull a single entry from the array and display it when the page loads.
I have gotten partway there using [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812218/jquery-select-random-json-object), however my attempt to adapt this answer causes the output html block to repeat the array items in sequence instead of simply picking one.

Here is a screenshot of what I get:
[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngaLQ.png)

I am likely doing something real stupid, and I hope someone can point this out.
My script is as follows:

```
    $.getJSON('recommend.json', function(data) {
    var entry = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];

$.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
        var html = '<div class="rec_img"><img src="./recs/' + entry['img'] + '" /></div>'; 
    html += '<span class="rec_title">' + entry['title'] + '</span><p>';
        html += '<span class="rec_author">' + entry['author'] + '</span><p>';
        html += '<span class="rec_blurb">' + entry['blurb']  + '</span>';

        $('#recblock').append(html).fadeIn();
      });
    });
```

Any questions just let me know.

Comment: "causes the output html block to repeat the array items in sequence". Do you expect $.each() to do something other than exactly that? If you just want a single item, remove the $.each() and it will only do it one time. You also have 2 open <p> tags with no </p>. Could be causing issues

Comment: As mentioned, "I am likely doing something real stupid" - I composed my code block from another unfinished Q+A, and I didn't know **what** $.each does! I'll look at this as a solution though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut this:

```
$.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
```

The whole purpose of `$.each` is to iterate over the entire array, which is the opposite of what you want. You're already defining `entry` earlier as a random entry from the data.

So you'll have:

```
$.getJSON('recommend.json', function(data) {
    var entry = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];

    var html = '<div class="rec_img"><img src="./recs/' + entry['img'] + '" /></div>'; 
    html += '<span class="rec_title">' + entry['title'] + '</span><p>';
    html += '<span class="rec_author">' + entry['author'] + '</span><p>';
    html += '<span class="rec_blurb">' + entry['blurb']  + '</span>';

    $('#recblock').append(html).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Okay, great, thanks. As mentioned, "I am likely doing something real stupid" and did not know what $.each does. I'll plug this in and give it a go.